# Can you read and write from and to APFS under High Sierra to FAT external hard-drives?

Tags: external-disk, ntfs, high-sierra, fat32, apfs

Like many I have backups on external hard-drives, some are in HFS and others are in FAT32 or NTFS.

What happens to those backups with APFS ? I won't be able to access, read and write to or from them if I update to High Sierra to get APFS ? Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand the question. High Sierra will still be able to read FAT, HFS+ and NTFS partitions, and the system partition may be converted to APFS. What exactly do you want to read from where and why are you afraid that might cease to work?

Comment: When you update your Mac(s) to High Sierra, only the internal flash devices you install High Sierra on will be converted to APFS. External devices will not be converted. If you are still concerned then unplug your external devices before upgrading.

Comment: I mean, once I update to High Sierra / APFS, will I still be able to copy to and from the external non-APFS hard drives from/to my Mac ?

Comment: Will I be able to copy a file from my Mac (APFS) to my external hard drive (FAT32 / NTFS) for example.

Comment: And will I be able to copy a file from my external hard drive (FAT32 / NTFS) to my Mac (APFS) for example.

Comment: Just normal basic interaction (copy, paste, read, write, execute) between a backup external hard drive (FAT32/NTFS) and a APFS Mac.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens to those backups with APFS?

Nothing happens.

Only the main internal drive is converted to APFS (and its contents are preserved anyways).

You will be able to use your external drives as before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing I struggle to grasp is that for example if you take an HFS drive, for example an external hard drive, with files on it. If you plug it on a NTFS or FAT computer under windows for example, you can't access it without tinkering and installing some drivers or software. Is it the same with APFS (on the computer's SSD) and FAT or NTFS external drives holding my backups. And if the FAT or NTFS drives are at least readable, can you execute and write from and to the drives using the APFS computer ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a NTFS or FAT computer"? There is no such thing as a "FAT computer" (nor NTFS). Those are file systems that can be used for partitions inside a disk.

Comment: I beg to differ.  I've got a FAT32-formatted flash drive that I use at the office for printing purposes, and since the update it has been rendered Read-Only.  Nothing changed; the OS simply refuses to write to it now—which sucks double since the printer refuses to recognize Mac-formatted drives.

Comment: @Kaji I used a FAT drive yesterday. Those "become" read only usually when there is slight fear system damage. A format fixes the problem unless it's a hardware issue.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto it's clear what I mean by "NTFS computer", you don't need a PHD to understand I'm, OF COURSE, talking about a computer with a NTFS filesystem ... I can't believe my question, yet so simple and basic, can't get a clear answer :/

Comment: @MFJC your question has already been answered. Nothing changes on your external drives. "NTFS computer" means nothing because a computer can have multiple partitions with multiple file systems and multiple operating systems. Windows is stupid and it cannot read and write HFS+... So what? MacOS can work on FAT and it can read NTFS (and write to it if you enable it) exactly the same on 10.11 and 10.12.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto NTFS computer just means a computer with only NTFS as a filesystem. I don't see why you stay fixated on this ... my question hasn't been answered and it's not so straightforward as Kaji's experience above shows it !

Comment: You could call them "NTFS drives", not NTFS computers. The file system is in a drive, not a feature of the computer. I use NTFS and FAT partitions daily on macOS 10.13 and yes, it is straightforward like it was on 10.12.